# ng-2 datepicker [(ngModel)] value not updated after form is submitted Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, ng2-datepicker

Hello Currently I am using ng-2 datepicker 1.8.3 version in angular 2

```
<ng2-datepicker  [options]="InvoicedDateOption" formControlName="invoiceDate"  [(ngModel)]="InvoiceDatepickerValue"  ></ng2-datepicker>
```

when I initially bind datepicker with datepicker option it works and binds ngModel values but when a form is submitted it ngModel values are gone.

options that I used to bind.

```
this.InvoicedDateOption = new DatePickerOptions({ autoApply: true, initialDate: new Date(), format: "MM-DD-YYYY" });
```

initially HTML look like below

[image]

But after a form is submitted that ng-reflect-model is gone and value of ngModel is not updated. see below image.[image]

I don't know after form submit when I again apply the same option to ng2-datepicker it is not bound to ngModel.

I searched many options but nothing is work. but it is still not working.

Please help!

Comment: can you please add stackblitz example?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-datepicker - have you tried `dateFormat` instead of `format`. Never used this component - but this looks like it may be the solution.